# Getting error while using Jasmine with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am using **jasmin** to test my **AngularJs** project with following code

**controllersSpec.js**

```
describe('myApp', function(){

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    it('should have a mailctrl', function() {
        expect(myApp.mailctrl).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

**controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mailctrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$rootScope', 'getMailData', '$angularCacheFactory',

    function ($scope, $routeParams, $rootScope, getMailData, $angularCacheFactory) {
           ##....controller content....##
    }
]);
```

**SpecRunner.html**

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jasmine-2.0.0/boot.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/controller.js"></script>
  <script src="../test/unit/controllersSpec.js"></script>`

Now when I am opening **Specrunner.html** in browser, I am getting following error 
**Expected undefined to be defined.** 
I have following question regarding above 
1) Where I am getting wrong ?
2) How can I use $rootScope variable of controller ?
3) Whats the difference in  *beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));*  and *beforeEach(angular.module('myApp'));* and *beforeEach(module('myApp'));*

**EDIT :**
I have modified the code as

```
describe('myApp', function(){
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));        
    it('should have a mailctrl', inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        var controller = $controller('mailctrl', { $scope: $rootScope.$new(), $rootScope: $rootScope });
        expect(controller).toBeDefined();
}));
```

and getting following error - 
**Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20%24routeParams**

If I add other params in $controller() (i.e. '$routeParams', 'getMailData') Error comes as they are undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You are making a mistake by trying to access your controller as a field on a module. in your test you should be injecting [`$controller`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$controller) into your test to create your controller. What that means is that you should be writing your tests like the following:

```
it('should have a mailctrl', inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
   var controller = $controller('mainctrl', { $scope: $rootScope.$new(), $rootScope: $rootScope, ...  }) // rest of your dependencies
   expect(controller).toBeDefined();
}));
```

2) See 1

3) `angular.mock.module` is used to register your module to the injector in your *tests*. It is the same thing as `module`. `angular.module` is used to create, register or retrieve a module for your *application*.

Regarding your edit:

You are not providing routeParams and any other service that your controller depends on so $injector does not know where to get them from and is throwing this error. $injector has to know what to inject for every parameter that is required by your controller. Your controller depends on

- `$rootScope`: provided by angular
- `$scope`: can be created by $rootScope.$new()
- `getMailData`: This is your service,  you have to provide a mock for this
- `$routeParams`: This is angular built-in structure but there is not a dedicated mock, but since it is a very simple object you can provide a mock for this yourself.
- `$angularCacheFactory`: this is a third party service and you have to provide a mock for this as well

So in the end you should be creating your controller like this:

```
it('should have a mailctrl', inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
   var controller = $controller('mainctrl', { 
         $scope: $rootScope.$new(), 
         '$routeParams': {}, // whatever  it needs to be to be able to test your controller
         $rootScope: $rootScope, 
         'getMailData': getMailDataMOCK // this object is created by you in your test code
         '$angularCacheFactory': $angularCacheFactoryMOCK
       }) 
   expect(controller).toBeDefined();
}));
```

If you don't provide any of these arguments then it will try to get it from $injector and will throw an exception when not found.

Comment: I have modified code as you told and got this  - "Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20%24routeParams in http://localhost/startmail/lib/angular/angular.min.js (line 6)"

Comment: hey @idursun please suggest, although I am getting your point yet it's still not working.

Comment: How did you modify your code? Can you update your question with the latest code?