# mock angularjs service for unit testing using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have an Angular App and I want to create  unit test cases for it using **jasmine**.
 
In my **AngularJS** app, I have a service as :

```
var canceler;
var myServices = angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource'])

myServices.factory('getData', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    var canceler;
    return {
        setData: function(url, callback, error) {
                    canceler = $q.defer();
                    $http.post(url, {}, {timeout:canceler.promise}).success(callback).error(error);
        },
        abort: function(){ canceler.resolve();}
    }
}]);
```

This service is being used by controller.

Now how can I provide a mock for this **"getData"** service to the injector I am using in controllerSpecs.js (for the unit testing using jasmine).

For the reference, the code of controllerSpecs.js is defined in  [Getting error while using Jasmine with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252369/getting-error-while-using-jasmine-with-angularjs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
//creation mock service
var mockGetData = {
  data: [],
  setData: function(url, callback, error){
    //emulate real work, any logic can be here
    data.push('called');
    callback(data);
  }
}
```

and use of the mock service

```
it('test description', inject(function ($rootScope, $controller){
  var scope = $rootScope.$new();
  var ctrl = $controller('TodoController', { $scope: scope, getData: mockGetData });
  //some test here....
}))
```

Comment: I am unable to understand that when we are putting the blank data and a function in the name of mockgetdata that does nothing, what will happen when I will call same function from jasmin to test it's functionality ?

Comment: @r.bhardwaj, you can emulate work of real GetData in the setData function, **data** property is not necessary, you just can save there some data during the test. I have updated the answer, but I don't know logic of your service so you can use any logic there.

Comment: got the point but one more thing to ask - if instead of creating the mock i get the 'getData' service using $injector.get( 'getData' ), what's harm in that ?

Comment: no harm. But unit testing means that you test each block independent from each other. So if your test fails and you use mock service, you can be sure that problem is not in the service. Otherwise you need more time to find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 11):

You can use AngularJS's `$provide` service. [This page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.testing_services) demonstrates how to mock the functionality of a service using [Jasmine's spies](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/). Basically in your Jasmine test you can include:

```
var getDataMock;

beforeEach(function() {
  getDataMock = {
    setData: jasmine.createSpy(), 
    abort: jasmine.createSpy()
  };

  module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('getData', getDataMock);
  });
});
```

This tells AngularJS that instead of using the real `getData` service, the mock will be used in its place. In this example, using a Jasmine spy for the mock lets you easily create expectations about how and when the getData service is called by the controller. You can alternatively set `getDataMock` to any other object, though it makes sense to support the same API as the real `getData` service.

For bonus points, you can specify the `getDataMock` object in a separate file, so that the mock may be easily used in any number of unit tests where the thing being tested uses `getData`. This however requires some configuration with whatever Jasmine runner you are using.

This is all assuming you wish to unit test the *controller*. If you want to unit test the `getData` service itself, AngularJS provides a nice [mocking utility](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend) specifically for http requests.

Comment: I used the getDataMock as you have written and getting following error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'running' of undefined at isSpecRunning in angular-mock.js

Comment: I used the getDataMock as you have written and getting following error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'running' of undefined at isSpecRunning in angular-mock.js

Comment: @r.bhardwaj - can you post your entire example in a JSFiddle?

Comment: I'm really needing to understand how to achieve your "bonus point". How can I specify a mock service in '$provide'?

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted answer.  It is worth noting that assigning the getDataMock in the beforeEach rather than outside ensures the spies get reset for each test.

Comment: links in answer are dead