# Karma error: myApp is not defined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test the Angular seed project with a clean install of Karma in a different directory. I haven't modified the Angular seed project. Why are `myApp` and `myApp.View1Ctrl` not defined?

My tests are:

```
describe("Unit Testing Examples", function () {

    //beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    it('should have a View1Ctrl controller', function () {
        expect(myApp).toBeDefined();
        expect(myApp.View1Ctrl).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

The output is:

```
INFO [watcher]: Changed file "C:/Projects/KarmaJasmine/KarmaJasmine/test/placeho
lder.js".                                                                       
Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 8.1) Unit Testing Examples should have a View1Ctrl controller FAILED                                                                  
    ReferenceError: myApp is not defined                                    
        at null.<anonymous> (C:/Projects/KarmaJasmine/KarmaJasmine/test/plac
eholder.js:8:16)                                                                
Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 8.1): Executed 6 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.054 secs)
Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 8.1): Executed 6 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0.061 secs / 0.054 s
ecs)
```

My karma.conf has the following section, and I confirmed that the files exist:

```
files: [
        '../AngularSeed/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        '../AngularSeed/app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        '../AngularSeed/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        '../AngularSeed/app/app.js',
        '../AngularSeed/app/components/**/*.js',
        '../AngularSeed/app/view*/**/*.js'
        , 'test/placeholder.js'
    ],
```

Please let me know if I need to post more details. I tried to read through all of the similar questions, and haven't found an answer.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252369/getting-error-while-using-jasmine-with-angularjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `myApp` variable that is not defined in your spec. Define it:

```
describe("Unit Testing Examples", function () {
    var myApp;

    beforeEach(function () {
        myApp = angular.module('myApp');
    });

    it('should have a View1Ctrl controller', function () {
        expect(myApp).toBeDefined();
        expect(myApp.controller('View1Ctrl')).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

There is also a [related jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Maslow/rQ3QT/) demonstrating the case.